# Is it possible to use querySelectorAll on an array of elements?

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

Say I have an array of DOM elements based on **any** `selector`

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
```

I have no idea what's included in `elems`, but let's assume that `elems.length > 0`

I'd like to use querySelectorAll (or some equivalent function) on `elems` to find all elements that match an additional selector.

```
// example: find all buttons with class `foo` within `elems` array
var buttons = elems.querySelectorAll("button.foo");
```

This doesn't work (for obvious reasons), but I'm unsure of how to do it otherwise :(

---

Here's the wrapper I created to work with the accepted answer from @Tibos

```
// Element.matches wrapper
(function(e){
  if (typeof e.matches !== "function") {
    e.matches = e.webkitMatchesSelector ||
                e.mozMatchesSelector    ||
                e.msMatchesSelector     ||
                e.oMatchesSelector      ||
                e.matchesSelector;
  }
})(Element.prototype);
```

Comment: Are you asking similar like this :
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/RanWJ/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`Element#matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches) method to filter out your original list:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
var buttons = Array.prototype.filter.call(elems, function(elem){ 
  return elem.matches('button');
});
```

Note that there are various names under which you find this method, you might want to wrap a function around them. (Please check the documentation!)

Another possibility is to get the intersection of the two sets of elements returned by `document.querySelectorAll` with the two selectors. There are various implementations of the intersection of two sets, feel free to use one that is to your liking. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript) provides some ideas.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I added the wrapper in my original question. Let me know if that looks okay to you ^.^

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList structure, so we change for an array list and we can use the function map.

```
  var lines = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  var paths = lines.map(function(elem){ 
    return elem.querySelector('button');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take as long as `matches` isn't more standard.

```
function getElementsFromParents(parentSelector, childSelector) {
    var elems = document.body.querySelectorAll(parentSelector);
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(elems, function matcher(arr, el) {
        var matches = el.querySelectorAll(childSelector);
        if (matches.length) Array.prototype.forEach.call(matches, function pusher(item) {
            arr.push(item);
        });
        return arr;
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here Is that You are Looking for If i'll get you `correct` !!

[SEE WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/RanWJ/1/)

Comment: This doesn't do what he wants. This finds subelements that match the query, where he wants elements of the array that match the query.